# Understanding __new__ and __init__ with multiple classes in python

Tags: python, inheritance, tuples, subclass, instantiation

so I am creating two subclasses of tuple and want to create either the one or the other based on some condition. I am aware of the Factory pattern, which would be the appropriate solution for this but in my specific situation I can't use it - and frankly I would like to understand :)
More specifically, I wonder when `__init__` is called after creating the object via `__new__` and when not (and why).

The following code example should illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class my_special_interval(tuple):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        print("my_special_interval")
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        if a > b:
            return super(my_special_interval, cls).__new__(my_special_interval, (a, b))
        else:
            obj = super(my_special_interval, cls).__new__(my_second_special_interval, (a, b))
            print("Explicit init necessary:")
            obj.__init__(a,b)
            return obj


class my_second_special_interval(tuple):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        print("my_second_special_interval")
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        if a > b:
            obj = super(my_second_special_interval, cls).__new__(my_special_interval, (a, b))
            print("Explicit init necessary:")
            obj.__init__(a,b)
        else:
            return super(my_second_special_interval, cls).__new__(my_second_special_interval, (a, b))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 2.0
    b = 1.0
    iv1 = my_special_interval(a,b)

    a = 1.0
    b = 2.0
    iv2 = my_special_interval(a,b)


    a = 2.0
    b = 1.0
    iv1 = my_second_special_interval(a,b)

    a = 1.0
    b = 2.0
    iv2 = my_second_special_interval(a,b)
```

This results in the following print-out:

```
my_special_interval
Explicit init necessary:
my_second_special_interval
Explicit init necessary:
my_special_interval
my_second_special_interval
```

Thx,

Mat

Comment: Why can't you use a factory actually ?

Comment: The reason is that my special interval is passed to another library's function which operates on several data types (tuple, for example). It does some computations and then tries to instantiate a new object with the same data type, filling its content with the result of the computation. Long story short - I want to use a library which doesn't give me this kind of flexibility...